# Memoizing a very heavy component with a frequently changing callback prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding best practices surrounding memoizing large React function components whose only frequently-changing prop is the reconstruction of a callback function.

Consider the following component:

```
function HeavyComponent(props: { item: string, callback: () => void }) {
  return (
    /* Assume that this component takes multiple hundred milliseconds to render */
  );
}

export default memo(HeavyComponent, (prev, next) => prev.item === next.item);
```

This is rendered by the following component:

```
function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<MyClass[]>([/* Assume I have a bunch of items here */]);

  function callback(item: MyClass) {
    // Do something with the item
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(x => (
        <HeavyComponent item={x.item} callback={() => callback(x)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
  
}
```

If I update my `items` array, any inlined callbacks, denoted by `() => callback(x)`, won't be recreated if the `item` property in `x` doesn't change for that instance of the memoized component. Then, if I followed the principles of immutability when updating my `items` array, invoking the callback from the memoized component will use the value of `x` that was last saved by the closure (which is now stale). This is causing me some headaches.

What is the best way to mitigate this problem while also minimizing the amount of re-renders the `HeavyComponent` must make? The dirty solution is to break the principles of immutability and just mutate the objects in my `items` array. But I'm convinced there is a better way.